# mysqli COUNT with WHERE and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I am trying to get the amount of records on specific dates. The problem is that when a date has no records it doesnt show the date.

```
$asksome= mysqli_query("
    SELECT COUNT(worker_id) AS amount, problem.datter AS datum
    FROM problem 
    WHERE worker_id = $idmed
    GROUP BY datter"
);
```

The structure looks like this:

```
worker_id | datter    | note
1         |2018-02-25 | 
1         |2018-02-26 | 
3         |2018-02-25 |
```

This is the query I am using. I want the query to show the dates even if the COUNT is 0. what i mean by this is i want the result to be like this:

```
count result | date
0            | 2018-02-24
2            | 2018-02-25
1            | 2018-02-26
0            | 2018-02-27
```

- - **For people finding this post not knowing what to do**: i fixed my issue by making another table that simply contained the specific dates that i want to check.
I used the following query:

```
SELECT weeks.week_id AS datum, COUNT(problem.datter) AS amount
    FROM weeks
    LEFT JOIN problem ON problem.datter = weeks.week_id
    GROUP BY weeks.week_id
```

Comment: Try putting your db's structure for the problem table so that a more clarifying help can be given.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: In your example, if you want to show the date even when the count = 0, then what is the date if worker_id = 2?

Comment: yes anonyXmous, that is what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You should make clear for the sql of how to handle the count when it is 0. In general, when using SQL's `SUM()` and `COUNT()` along with the `GROUP BY` statement, 0 is never output. And that is because, the `GROUP BY` clause has nothing to group with when no records for your count of 0 exist.

For that you can use the COALESCE expression.

You can see its documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

So in your example, the sql query should be:

```
SELECT COALESCE (SELECT COUNT(worker_id) AS amount, problem.datter AS datum
FROM problem 
WHERE worker_id = $idmed
GROUP BY datter"), 0);
```